# Passing row of static 2-d array to function in C++

Tags: c++, function, arrays

This is a really elementary question. Nonetheless, I haven't found a solution after studying dozens of semi-relevant examples online.

I have a two-dimensional array of doubles whose size is known at compile time: `double demPMFs[ NUM_DEM_PARAMS ][ NUM_AGE_CATEGORIES ]`. Array entries are populated by input files early in the program. I'd like to pass individual rows as one-dimensional arrays to functions later in the program. I'd ideally like to maintain separate names for each row:

```
#define LSPAN_PMF demPMFs[0][]
#define FLEDGE_PMF demPMFs[1][]
#define PAIR_PMF demPMFs[2][]
#define BIRTH_AGE_PMF demPMFs[3][]
#define SPLIT_AGE_PMF demPMFs[4][]
```

(Here, `NUM_DEM_PARAMS = 5;`). Below is a failed attempt to pass a row to a function:

```
int calcDeath( double demPMFs[][ NUM_AGE_CATEGORIES ] ) {
  int age_death = rmultinom( LSPAN_PMF, NUM_AGE_CATEGORIES );
  return age_death;
} 

int rmultinom( const double p_trans[], int numTrans )
   // ...[code snipped]...
}
```

I'm getting compiler errors about the prototypes now; I expect to run into problems with the `const` declaration too. I can go into the details of the errors if people think they're relevant, but I suspect there's a lot to set straight already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `array[index][]`, use `array[index]`:

```
#define LSPAN_PMF demPMFs[0]
// ... etc.
```

But why obfuscate working with arrays so much? Using named indices would be much clearer:

```
enum {
    IndexLspan,
    IndexFledge,
    // ...
};

int calcDeath( double demPMFs[][ NUM_AGE_CATEGORIES ] ) {
    int age_death = rmultinom( demPMFs[IndexLspan], NUM_AGE_CATEGORIES );
```

Continuing, why not use the containers from the C++ standard library in the first place?

Comment: By containers, do you mean vectors? I wanted to be able to use pre-existing random number generators, but I suppose I could overload them to take vector inputs too. Thanks for the enum recommendation; I hadn't thought this through so deeply b/c it's mostly icing on the input cake, so to speak.

Comment: While i don't know exactly how you are using your data; `vector` or `map`, possibly combined with using structures would probably make it all more readable.